# How to stop ListView scrolling while in progress programatically?

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView with a bunch of items. If I make a big swipe, it will keep scrolling on its own for a few seconds until the scrolling slows and eventually stops.

How can I cancel this scrolling animation/movement programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `_listController.animateTo(offset, duration: duration, curve: curve)` to scroll to specific position in order to stop scrolling.

or do this:

```
physics: BooleanVariable ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```